# Parse hostname and protocol from URL in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: url, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there any way to get the hostname and protocol from an URL?

My use case:

1. On installation user inputs the application and API URL
2. Get hostname `allowedOrigins` configuration

Example url:

```
https://somelink.com/#/login
https://someapilink.com/api/
```

Desired result:

```
https://somelink.com
https://someapilink.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you really needed full URL parsing, you might make use of [`ParseURL` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-parseurlw).

But if you only need the hostname and protocol, I'd resort to parsing the URL on your own:

```pascal
function GetUrlHostName(Url: string): string;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  P := Pos('://', Url);
  if P > 0 then
  begin
    Result := Copy(Url, P + 3, Length(Url) - P - 1);
    P := Pos('/', Result);
    if P > 0 then Result := Copy(Result, 1, P - 1);
    P := Pos('#', Result);
    if P > 0 then Result := Copy(Result, 1, P - 1);
    P := Pos(':', Result);
    if P > 0 then Result := Copy(Result, 1, P - 1);
  end;
end;

function GetUrlProtocol(Url: string): string;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  P := Pos('://', Url);
  if P > 0 then
  begin
    Result := Copy(Url, 1, P - 1);
  end;
end;
```

*(The `GetUrlHostName` does not take possible username and password into account)*